# Language choice for small memory footprint

Tags: programming-languages, memory-management

I have a tiny VPS where the memory is very scarce. I was thinking that for fun I might want to write some servers to run on it, that use as little memory as possible. Maybe something like a git-daemon, or anything else that comes up later, there are a lot of interesting techs out there which I'd love to try out for myself.

What programming language would you recommend if memory usage has the highest priority? I'm glad (even prefer) to learn something new.

Comment: Something close to the metal, indeed. Of course, another question is whether you *want* to program a nontrivial application in C.

Comment: You mean like Windows? They managed to make memory consumption (uh, usage?) highest priority.

Answer (score 3):

[Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) can be extremely compact.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check it out. Forth looks very different from everything else I've tried before, should be a good exercise (and hopefully something useful in the end).

Answer (score 2):

The good old C, unless you're brave enough to all way down to assembly.

Why?
You probably don't want any VMT.
You probably don't want any dynamic typing.
You probably don't want any memory hungry VM.

It's the standard non assembly language for microcontrollers (very little memory), and C low memory footprint is one of the reasons.

Comment: You also don't want a lot of code made of the weak instructions typical of low-end microprocessors, because that will burn a lot of space doing general purpose things such as "servers".  Better to have dense virtual instruction set and pay the cost of the interpreter one time.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a language that has a dense virtual machine instruction set.  Another answer here suggested Forth, which is surely a VM, but which I think fails that test by virtue of using pointers (non-dense fullwords) to select execution routines.

Google's compiled version of Java, [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)), is supposed to be designed with the intent to minimize memory footprint while being pretty fast to interpret.  Being open source, apparantly you can get it and use it for your own purposes.  You can likely bend it to avoid use of garbage collection to help manage the data storage footprint.

There is also a [Cint](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fportal.acm.org%2Fft_gateway.cfm%3Fid%3D29670%26type%3Dpdf&ei=LaZaTY2-D5L0tgeFhrGsCw&usg=AFQjCNE3_Pn05WK_cz9KBkzId6QAgwwMMA), an interpreter for C with a small VM.  Probably not as fast as Dalvik, which uses simulated registers rather than a stack.

Comment: Any threaded code Forth implementation is, practically, a virtual machine with an extremely dense and *extensible* instructions set. Any fixed instructions set VM code will be much less compact than a properly written Forth code.

Comment: @SK-logic: A Forth instruction set isn't dense information wise. You are using a full pointer (say, 32 bits) to point to one of perhaps 1000 Forth word implementations. You are getting 10 bits of information stored in every 32, or about 30%. A Huffman-encoded P-code can achieve much higher densities.

Comment: @SK-logic: ... "extensible" part of the instruction set for VM is the classic "Subroutine call" opcode. Works just fine.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: not quite a call. It is more akin to higher order functions, as Forth words can operate on an arbitrary stack depth. And, by the way, it is not mandatory to use a direct threaded code. I've seen forth implementations with a single byte word tags.

Comment: @SK-logic: True, but most applications don't need that much power, and you can always cheat when it is necessary, at very little actual loss in productivity (I've been building embedded systems for literally decades).   Yes, a Forth application that used small "words" would be close to what I suggested; it wouldn't be hard to Huffman encode them either, but that was my original point.

Comment: @Ira Baxter, think of a balance between a compact code representation and a runtime performance. An indirect threaded code is ok. Direct threaded code is fast. But decoding each next opcode from a bitstream is going to be dead slow.

Comment: @SK-logic: You can balance decoding with memory unit aligned access and do just fine. The obvious trick is byte-oriented huffman codes. You can nibble-orient without much loss. The Dalvik guys insist on only 16 bit, two-byte aligned words and have quite fast decoders. Really clever guys generate huffman encoding, and then find common instruction sequences to add as additional opcodes to fill out the pure huffman scheme to some easily decoded boundary; this buys them better compression as well as faster execution.

Comment: Thanks, Dalvik sounds like a very interesting idea. At the moment, though, getting and compiling the VM seems like a non-trivial process. But that won't stop me (hopefully). Any suggestions, besides using "dvk" froom Google Code?

Comment: @Greg: You could always implement UCSD P-code, or the Java opcode set.  Both are very well documented and relatively compact.